# How to cast when chaining methods in C#

Tags: c#, syntax, casting

I'm trying to code something, and I always return the object itself so I can keep chaining. Like this

```
object.SetThis().SetThat().SetThisThirdThing().setThisFourthThing();
```

I return this in all my methods so I can keep doing this. But one of my methods is something I made in my base class, which of course then returns the base class.

So instead of `public MyClass SetThat()` it returns `public SuperClass SetThat()`. And because it returns `SuperClass` and not `MyClass` I can't call `SetThisThirdThing()` because the base class doesn't know about it.

So how do I cast it so I can keep the chain? What is the syntax? I tried

```
object.SetThis().(MyClass)SetThat().SetThisThirdThing().setThisFourthThing();
```

Or is there a way to make a superClass method return the subclass when called from the subclass without having to override it in all the subclasses?

This is one of the things that all the subclasses have in common, so it would be really nice if I would be able to circumvent this somehow without having to override it in all my subclasses.

Comment: Why don't you just cast the first element? ((MyClass)object).SetThis().SetThat()

Comment: For reference, "dotting" is more typically called a "fluent interface".

Comment: @Mitch Not sure that's true, fluent interface is really just a subset of [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)

Comment: `method chaining` is fun and all, but don't do this.  You'll look back at this code next week and wonder what on earth you were doing.  Logically, it's two different operations. Use multiple statements.

Comment: @PhilippeParé because `SetThat` returns `SuperClass` and that's what they want to cast.

Comment: Yeah of course didn't realize

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there a way to make a superClass method return the subclass when called from the subclass without having to override it in all the subclasses?

Can you make the superclass generic?

```
public class SuperClass<T> where T: SuperClass<T>
{
    public T SetThis()
    {
        ....
        return (T)this;
    }
}

public class SubClass : SuperClass<SubClass>
{
}
```

Note that it's not 100% guaranteed since you could also do this:

```
public class EvilSubClass : SuperClass<SubClass>
{
}
```

which fits the generic contraints, but now the return type of `SetThis()` is `SubClass` and not `EvilSubClass`

Comment: This is an excellent solution to my predicament, I think. I'll just try this.

Comment: This seemed to work fine for that so I'm going to accept it as an answer. But now I have a problem a place where I want to take the generic superclass as a method parameter. I can't just use, public MySuperClass addThis(MySuperClass theObject) because it says "The name MySuperClass doesn't exist in the current context"? How to fix this? :)

Comment: I'd ask that as a separate question - but broadly you could split the non-generic methods into a non-generic superclass. But it depends on how you intend to _use_ the superclass.  If generics break everything downstream then overloads may be the way to go.

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of what you mean by overloads? Like overriding the method in all the subclasses? It's a method I need in all my 16 subclasses, which is why I'd like it in my superclass, but doing what is suggested here, which fixes the question I asked, breaks everything else.

Comment: Overrides won't work because you can't change the return type.  Overloads (same name but different parameters) would only work in you change one of the _input_ parameter types.  So you may just have to implement the methods in all subclasses.  If you want better answers you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = ((MyType)myObject.SetThis()).SetThat();
```

P.S You should avoid doing that, since it can become quite confusing to read.

Comment: Parhaps expand on why one should avoid this.

Comment: @MrPaulch thought it was obvious:)

Comment: Obvious to you and maybe obvious to me. But not obvious to everyone. It's just a suggestion to improve your answer!

Comment: I believe the OP wants to cast the result of `SetThat`, not the result of `SetThis`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
((MyClass)object.SetThis().SetThat()).SetThisThirdThing()
```

Comment: This doesn't work - in this expression, the return value of `SetThisThirdThing()` will be cast to `MyClass`. It would be the same as `(MyClass)object.SetThis().SetThat().SetThisThirdThing()`.

Comment: @Glorfindel you're right, my mistake. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To cast a (sub)expression, you need to put the class name in front (and use parentheses).

```
((MyClass)obj.SetThis().SetThat()).SetThisThirdThing().setThisFourthThing();
```

(note that `object` is a reserved word, so you can't use it as a variable name)

An alternative is to use the [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) keyword:

```
(obj.SetThis().setThat() as MyClass).SetThisThirdThing().setThisFourthThing();
```

Note that this will behave differently if `setThat()` doesn't return a `MyClass`;
the first version will throw an `InvalidCastException`, the second version a `NullReferenceException` because `as` returns `null` if the cast is not possible.

Comment: If you use `as MyClass` however, you can get null reference exceptions.

Comment: In the same scenario, if you used a direct cast you'd just get a different exception

Answer (score 0):

Just use parenthesis:

```
(MyClass)(object.SetThis().SetThat()).SetThisThirdThing().setThisFourthThing();
```

I don't know why the `object` is there, but you can safely remove it.

```
(MyClass)(SetThis().SetThat()).SetThisThirdThing().setThisFourthThing();
```

Comment: The object was just there to show I was doing it on an object. Could just aswell have been myObject.SetThis().SetThat()

Comment: `object` was the variable name.  But I do like the extra parenthesis that make it very obvious what is being casted.

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying your classes, you can also write an extension method `As` like this

```
public static T As<T>(this MyBaseClass obj) where T : MyBaseClass
{
   return (T)obj;
}
```

--

Usage would be similar to this

```
new MyChildClass().SetBase().As<MyChildClass>().SetThis();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like this? A simple `Cast` method to help you cast it back to the correct type...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new MyClass();
        //obj.SetThis().SetThat().SetThisThirdThing().setThisFourthThing(); // Compile error
        obj.SetThis().SetThat().Cast<MyClass>().SetThisThirdThing().setThisFourthThing();
    }
}

class SuperClass
{
    public SuperClass SetThat()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public T Cast<T>() where T : SuperClass
    {
        return (T)this;
    }
}

class MyClass : SuperClass
{
    public MyClass SetThis()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public MyClass SetThisThirdThing()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public MyClass setThisFourthThing()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```